# How to get external images into dreamweaver panel

Tags: image, dreamweaver, filepath

my question is incredibly simple yet I haven't been able to find an answer online. I made a small image in photoshop and am trying to incorporate it in my current website. I don't know how to get the image into dreamweaver into the image folder in the dreamweaver panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the image into the image directory of your root folder and simply add the markup where you want to add the image.

```
<img src = "[your image link]" />
```

Or simply add the images using the files panel- Insert->Images->Select your image then press ok.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

1- ctrl + Alt + I and choose your image from the dialog
2- copy manually the image you created to the website directory on your hard drive

hope this hepls!

Answer (score 0):

Your image folder should be stored locally on your machine in your site-root folder.

In Photoshop: Save for Web Devices, Navigate to the Root Folder where your site is stored, Open Image Folder and Save Image in that location.

In Dreamweaver: Go to Files Panel, hit refresh button and the image should now appear in the images folder.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with file paths, how do I get to the Root Folder? Im using a mac and I can't find any of the dreamweaver files in Finder.

Comment: In dreamweaver, go to "Site" in the top menu bar, click manage sites, find the name of the site you are working on, select it and click edit. You will see a file path in the dialog box and that is where your site root is. If you prefer you can change that location by selecting the little folder icon and putting in a location where you can remember. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this by far is too put your cursor on the part of the page you'd like you picture to reside.

Then using the top menus click "Insert" and then "Image", once you have done this you'll be able to find your image on your local computer or network and you will be prompted to save it to your site with the site directory already up - then just choose where to save your file.

It's best practice to save all images into the images folder.

Hope that helps!